# Laravel 5.0 utf8 convert?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, laravel-5

I am in trouble.

> windows 8.1
>   xampp 3.2.1
>   php 5.4
>   Laravel 5.1
>   Lang utf8(Japanese)

MySql

```
character_set_client      utf8
character_set_connection  utf8
character_set_database    utf8
character_set_filesystem  binary
character_set_results     utf8
character_set_server      utf8
character_set_system      utf8
character_sets_dir        C:\xampp\mysql\share\charsets\
```

php.ini

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll 

mbstring.language = Japanese 
mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8 
mbstring.http_input = auto 
mbstring.http_output = UTF-8 
mbstring.encoding_translation = On 
mbstring.detect_order = auto 
mbstring.substitute_character = none; 
mbstring.func_overload = 0
```

insert action

```
public function register(Request $request) {
$group = new Group;
$group->name = $request->name;
$group->remarks = $request->remarks;

$validator = $this->validator($request->all());
if ($validator->fails()) {
    $this->throwValidationException(
        $request, $validator
    );
}

$group->save();

return redirect()->guest('master/group');
}
```

view insert tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In this source code, it will be insert without problems.

However, it is garbled when you update.

update action

```
public function update(Request $request) { 
$group = Group::find($request->id); 
$group->name = $request->name; 
$group->remarks = $request->remarks; 
$group->user_id = $request->user_id; 

$validator = $this->validator($request->all()); 
if ($validator->fails()) { 
    $this->throwValidationException( 
        $request, $validator 
    ); 
} 

$group->save(); 

return redirect()->guest('master/group'); 
}
```

I tried several.

1. `var_dump($request->name);` // NG
2. `var_dump(utf8_encode($request->name));` // NG
3. `var_dump(utf8_decode($request->name));` // OK

When you update has caused the question to whether a correct code to carry out the `utf8_decode ()`.

What, what's wrong is setting?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any encoders/decoders.

Instead of the `var_dump()`, do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` and show us the output.  The hex should mostly be groups of 6 hex digits: `E8xxyy`.  (Space is `20`.)

If you don't get hex like that, then the data was not stored correctly.  Otherwise, the problem is on the output.

To see the hex in PHP:

```
$hex = unpack('H*', $text);
echo implode('', $hex);
```

Again look for lots of `E8xxyy`.  This will further narrow down where the problem is.